# create background android service to decline incoming phone calls

Tags: java, android, telephonymanager

looking for resources on how to create an ongoing background service started by an android app which declines/silences and logs incoming phone calls. This must not use deprecated APIs/permissions for Android 10.

Comment: Only default dialer app can decline incoming calls. Background services that used to do that only worked on low apis (android 5 and lower) by using "hackish" methods like reflection or injecting headset key press command but it won't work on any modern device.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A way to decline an incoming call is to hang up the call but permissions are needed.
Try to follow this (this is the concept) :

1. Request Run time permissions(READ_PHONE_STATE, 
    CALL_PHONE)
2. Create a broadcast receiver that waits for incoming calls
3. When incoming call is detected hang it up.

Rely on this resource(here you have detailed instructions) :
https://dev.to/nikola/how-to-make-a-native-android-app-that-can-block-phone-calls--4e15

Comment: turns out there are a couple more permissions needed such as ANSWER_PHONE_CALLS for api v28+